# focus on the current active element

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to focus on an element based on its native element.

I am using Angular 2,`this.elem.nativeElement` gives me the entire required details. But I am not able to set the focus on 1 of the elements of 
       `this.elem.nativeElement`.

I want to focus on `id="dateEdit"`.

Kindly help me.

```
<div class="mydp" id="dtpid">
    <div class="selectiongroup">
        <div [formGroup]="form" class="ntt">
            <input type="text" id="{{controlName}}" [formControlName]="controlName" (click)="openBtnClicked()" (blur)="changeValue($event.currentTarget.value)" class="datePickAtUnique selection form-control" [ngClass]=" 
        {'invaliddate': invalidDate&&opts.indicateInvalidDate}" placeholder=" 
        {{opts.showDateFormatPlaceholder? 
        opts.dateFormat:opts.customPlaceholderTxt}}">
        </div>
        <span id="datePickAT" class="selbtngroup" [style.height]="opts.height">
        <button type="button" id="dateEdit" aria-label="Clear Date" 
        class="btnclear" *ngIf="selectionDayTxt.length>0" 
         (click)="removeBtnClicked()" [ngClass]="{'btnclearenabled': 
       !opts.componentDisabled, 'btncleardisabled': opts.componentDisabled}" 
       [disabled]="opts.componentDisabled">
          <span class="icon icon-cross" [ngStyle]="{'line-height': 
          opts.height}"></span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" id="dateChange" aria-label="Open Calendar" class="btnpicker" (click)="openBtnClicked()" [ngClass]=" 
        {'btnpickerenabled': !opts.componentDisabled, 'btnpickerdisabled': 
         opts.componentDisabled, 'disabled': disabled}" [disabled]="opts.componentDisabled">
            <span class="icon icon-calendar" [ngStyle]="{'line-height': 
             opts.height}"></span>
        </button>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: I have tried using "document.getElementById("dateEdit").focus();", but everytime the focus shifts to the first element having this id. It doesn't focus based on the nativeElement.

Comment: What do you mean by "shifts to the first element having this id"? Do you have more than one element having this id?

Comment: @DiabolicWords I am calling this component thrice in a page. So I want the focus depending on the parent ie. nativeElement.

Comment: I'd recommend to use and additional id fragment you hand in at creation time by `@Input`. So that you can extend your button id like `id="dateEdit{{uniqueId}}"`. Then you can address the wanted id by, lets say `"dateEdit0"`, `"dateEdit1"` and so forth, no matter how often the component repeats on the same page.

Comment: Element ids are [required to be unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) if specified.  If they aren't, you need to fix that first.

Answer (score 0):

There is a github repo by Chris Turnbull. Here is the link: [Angular directive to set an element focus via the controller](http://%22https://github.com/christurnbull/ng-set-focus%22)

Include this into your project. Basically what you have to do is use **ng-set-focus** attribute on any element that you want to set focus on and give it a value(has to be unique). Then in the controller use **$broadcast** to set focus on that element. You have to inject the ngSetFocus service in your controller.

Example:

```
In dom:
    <button ng-click="setFocusHere('button1')">Button 1</button>
    <button ng-click="setFocusHere('button2')">Button 2</button>

In controller:
     <script>
  angular.module('ngSetFocusDemo', ['ngSetFocus'])
    .controller('DemoController', function($scope) {

      $scope.setFocusHere = function(el){
        console.log(el)
        $scope.$broadcast(el);
      }

    })
</script>
```

[Working example here](https://embed.plnkr.co/HBGq2Z3ERqukk7TGLlGt/)

Comment: Won't I be able to achieve it purely with JavaScript ?

Answer (score 0):

```
As my code shows, there are 2 buttons and I wanted the focus on the first button with id="dateEdit". I had said that .focus() always points to the first element with this id, it was because I was calling the .focus() before the element even loaded, for this I changed my angular 2 condition from "ngIf" to "hidden". I came up with this, that helped me,

var x = this.elem.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
setTimeout(function(){
x.focus();
},100);
```